# What's the database impact of Central Administration Site Export? Locked for Writes AND Reads?

Tags: 2010, powershell, import, export

We're about to move a site from a parallel site collection into a subsite of the other site collection.  Both SC's are in the same Web Application.  We have not been able to get the command line version of Export-SPWeb to work (see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16882/migrating-a-site-from-one-sc-to-another-contenttype-problems) but we have been able to get the Central Administration export site functionality to work.  Unfortunately we can't enable UseSqlSnapshot because it's not an option on the web interface.

So my question is:  **does executing a Site Export from Central Administration lock the database for Writes AND Reads?  or just Writes?**  And does sharepoint handle this gracefully?

Comment: Sean McDonough says on his blog: "Prior to SharePoint 2010, site collection backup operations required some form of site collection lock to avoid data changes that would compromise the consistency of the backup being created. Locks of this type impacted the end-user experience adversely by preventing writes and updates to the target site collection until the backup operation could be completed."

http://secretsofsharepoint.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/09/22/improve-site-collection-backups-and-exports-with-sql-server-snapshots-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a test on this right now.  Kicked off a Site export (not a Site Collection) (Central Administration > Backup & Restore > Export a Site or List > Selected Site, but no list)  and am able to use & make changes to the site being exported, during export.

**Answer: nothing is locked, site is usable.**  Perhaps the web triggered export is using  /UseSqlSnapshot by silent default?